# Multiple transactions in geth

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions

I'm implementing a private ethereum blockchain network with geth and I can't perform multiple transactions in a block, coming from the same account, is this the default behavior or is it a bug?

Comment: It is possible to include multiple transactions from the same account in mainnet Ethereum.